# VB.net Thread safe method to add a listview subitem?

Tags: vb.net, listview, thread-safety

I am trying to add a subitem to a listview in a threadsafe manner.

In a single threaded application it works like so:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 to lvMembers.Items.Count - 1
    Dim lv As ListViewItem = lvMembers.Items(i)
    Dim str As String = lv.Text.ToString
    If str.Contains("value")
    lv.SubItems.Add("OK")
    lv.SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.Green

    Else
    lv.SubItems.Add("FAILED")
    lv.SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.Red

    End If
    Next
```

However if run in another thread it causes a cross threading error.

I have looked at examples of delegate subs that use Invoke, but all examples i have seen involve updating the text property of an object, and i cant get my head round how to apply the concept to actually add a subitem to a listview.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Can you post how do you use delegates?

Comment: Well my problem is if i run this in anything other than the main UI thread, it throws a cross threading exception. If fails at the second line, so i guess i will have to change my whole approach, but dont know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread-safe simplified way to add a new ListViewItem to a ListView:

```
Private Sub AddListViewItem(ByVal name As String, ByVal subitem1 As String, ByVal subitem2 As String)
    ListView1.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                              Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(name)
                              lvi.SubItems.Add(subitem1)
                              lvi.SubItems.Add(subitem2)
                              ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {lvi})
                          End Sub)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that I use over and over again for my own uses. It supports passing variables. My list view in this example has 1 item and 2 sub items (site, group, pagerank), so modify it for your own uses:

The delegate:

```
Private Delegate Sub ListViewAddItem_delegate(ByVal name As String, ByVal group As String, ByVal pagerank As String)
Private Sub ListViewAddItem(ByVal name As String, ByVal group As String, ByVal pagerank As String)
    If Me.ListView1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New ListViewAddItem_delegate(AddressOf ListViewAddItem)
        Me.ListView1.BeginInvoke(d, {name, group, pagerank})
    Else
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(name)
        lvi.SubItems.Add(group)
        lvi.SubItems.Add(pagerank)
        ListView1.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {lvi})
        ListView1.Update()
    End If
End Sub
```

How to call it:

```
Dim Name as string = "Test"
Dim Group As String = "TestGroup"
Dim PR As String = "10"
ListViewAddItem(Name, Group, PR)
```

I added the "dim xxx as string" stuff just to show that Name Group PR were strings when calling ListViewAddItem()

I noticed no answer has been chosen. Do us all a favor and choose one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private delegate sub deladdtolist

Private sub addtolist
  If InvokeRequired Then
    del.Invoke( new deladdtolist(AddressOf addtolist))
  else
    For i As Integer = 0 to lvMembers.Items.Count - 1
    Dim lv As ListViewItem = lvMembers.Items(i)
    Dim str As String = lv.Text.ToString
    If str.Contains("value")
    lv.SubItems.Add("OK")
    lv.SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.Green

    Else
    lv.SubItems.Add("FAILED")
    lv.SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.Red

    End If
    Next
  End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'sample data for the ListView
        Dim ipsumA() As String = New String() {"Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", _
                                               "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", _
                                               "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", _
                                               "tempor", "incididunt", "ut", "labore", _
                                               "et", "dolore", "magna", "aliqua", "Ut", _
                                               "enim", "ad", "minim", "veniam", "quis", _
                                               "nostrud", "exercitation", "ullamco", _
                                               "laboris", "nisi", "ut", "aliquip", "ex", _
                                               "ea", "commodo", "consequat", "Duis", "aute", _
                                               "irure", "dolor", "in", "reprehenderit", "in", _
                                               "voluptate", "velit", "esse", "cillum", "dolore", _
                                               "eu", "fugiat", "nulla", "pariatur", "Excepteur", _
                                               "sint", "occaecat", "cupidatat", "non", "proident", _
                                               "sunt", "in", "culpa", "qui", "officia", "deserunt", _
                                               "mollit", "anim", "id", "est", "laborum"}

        Dim lvi As New List(Of ListViewItem)

        For Each s As String In ipsumA
            Dim nLVI As New ListViewItem(s)
            lvi.Add(nLVI)
        Next

        ListView1.Items.AddRange(lvi.ToArray)

        'colorize from another thread
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf thrd)
        t.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub thrd()
        If ListView1.InvokeRequired Then
            ListView1.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf thrd))
        Else
            For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
                Dim lv As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items(i)
                Dim str As String = lv.Text.ToString
                If str.ToLower.Contains("ut") Then
                    lv.SubItems.Add("OK")
                    lv.SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.Green

                Else
                    lv.SubItems.Add("FAILED")
                    lv.SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.Red
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```